# Load Aurora exported csv files from S3 to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-aurora

I need to load data from Aurora (MySQL) to Redshift and using S3 is one of the available options. I can extract data from Aurora (MySQL) to S3 using and load them to Redshift using 2 statements:

```
SELECT *
FROM data_table
INTO OUTFILE S3 's3-XXX://bucket_name/aurora_files/data_table'
    FORMAT CSV HEADER
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    OVERWRITE ON;


copy data_table
from 's3://bucket_name/aurora_files/data_table.part_00000'
access_key_id 'XXX'
secret_access_key 'XXX'
csv
delimiter ';'
ignoreheader 1
timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'
region 'XXX';
```

This works wilt single file explicitly mentioned when loading to Redshift, but if I try loading multiple files using manifest, I get the following error:

```
[2022-03-15 14:13:23] [XX000] ERROR: S3 path "s3-XXX://bucket_name/aurora_files/data_table.part_00000" has invalid format. 
[2022-03-15 14:13:23] Detail:  
[2022-03-15 14:13:23] -----------------------------------------------  
[2022-03-15 14:13:23] error:  S3 path "s3-XXX://bucket_name/aurora_files/data_table.part_00000" has invalid format.  
[2022-03-15 14:13:23] code:      8001  
[2022-03-15 14:13:23] context:   Parsing S3 Bucket  
[2022-03-15 14:13:23] query:   326558  
[2022-03-15 14:13:23] location:  s3_utility.cpp:133  
[2022-03-15 14:13:23] process:   padbmaster [pid=22440]  
[2022-03-15 14:13:23] -----------------------------------------------
```

Statement that are returning errors:

```
SELECT *
FROM data_table
INTO OUTFILE S3 's3-XXX://bucket_name/aurora_files/data_table'
    FORMAT CSV HEADER
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    MANIFEST ON
    OVERWRITE ON;

copy data_table
from 's3://bucket_name/aurora_files/data_table.manifest'
access_key_id 'XXX'
secret_access_key 'XXX'
csv
delimiter ';'
ignoreheader 1
timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'
region 'XXX'
manifest;
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Does the [STL_LOAD_ERRORS - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) table contain any details about that loading error?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the file names in your manifest are not in the correct format.

`s3://bucket_name/aurora_files/data_table.part_00000` which works and

`s3-eu-west-1://bucket_name/aurora_files/data_table.part_00000` which doesn't.

I expect you just need to **remove the region specifier**.

Answer (score 1):

Right. The was in the command that was used to create S3 file. There is not need to specify region

```
INTO OUTFILE S3 's3-XXX://bucket_name/aurora_files/data_table'.
```

Keeping just s3:// fixes the manifest and files load.

```
INTO OUTFILE S3 's3://bucket_name/aurora_files/data_table'.
```